# mongoDB multiple instances or multiple databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I chose to use docker with node-js and mongoDB to make a game, and set all of my game sections (battles, chat, resources, etc) into different servers so each section will have its own process, because for example my resource server will be running a lot as it will do all the calculation of the resources of each user every second and will handle requests from other servers, like if the user have enough resources to build a building or how much resources the player will lose if attacked etc.

For my alpha and beta versions i'm planning on running one server, that will run all the sections of my game, but the way i'm doing it now, every section is having its own mongodb instance, so i have resourcesDB, mainDB (users info, login info and stuff), all the instances won't have many collections, for example resourcesDB have only 2 collections, resource collections, which each user will have 1 document with stuff related to resources, and logs collection that will store all user's usage (building upgrades, battles lost etc.)

I have read about multi instances on the same servers, and they all said that its not the best way to do it, as it will have an impact on my performance, in the future i am planning on separate all of my sections into different servers so each section will have its own server and DB server if needed.

1. Should I maybe build 1 instance and separate it on the database level? that means that I will have to connect to the same instance from multiple servers, resource server will update all the user's resources count every second, combine that with battle server that will update the state of troops in DB and more for each war that is going on, i will also have chat database that will be updating with each private message or chat message, will it cause any issues? or it will cause problems only if I connect to a single database and separate it on the collections level?
2. Is there a reason why i should not continue with creating multiple instances? i read that there might be a problem with config files if using multiple instances on same server, but i assume docker handle that part.

UPDATE - i have found an excellent answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156811/mongodb-in-micro-services-structure/156984#156984

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using microservice architecture for your app is good idea but I don't see a good reason to separate the database. MongoDB can handle it for you (Sharding). Also MongoDB not block write to collection A when you write to collection B. if you will separate your app to multiple database it will be hard to do backups and to maintain the app.

You can read here about concurrency options for MongoDB and see how MongoDB handle collection level locking.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/